# Spring Data Transaction spanning multiple Repositories

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have the need to insert 2 different entities into 2 different tables, using the same transaction. If the second insert fails, the first one should be rolled back.

Is there any way of doing this nicely?

Pseudo code:

```
start tx
repo1.save(myEntity);
repo2.save(anotherEntity);
try commit
```

I know you can leverage `@Transactioal` but only on method level?

Comment: Wrap the calls in a single service method which itself is annotated with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Sure, you need XA JDBC drivers and a transaction manager.  Spring can do this easily with annotations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. you need check that you don't have set autocommit = false.
2. wrap save operations into one service method and make it `@Transactional`. But if you use `save()` custom method check that save in not marked as `@Transactional` with propagation level required_new or nested. If you need you can use `REQUIRES_NEW` for saving service method to make this service method transaction independent of other transactions.

also you can wrap in with TransactionTemplate.

```
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
    @Override
    public void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
            repo1.save(myEntity);
            repo2.save(anotherEntity);
    });
```

Comment: Great Answer! Solved my problem of committing multiple repositories at one shot.

Answer (score 10):

It is usually a wrong idea to have `@Transactional` declared around repository methods.

Repositories are only for you to access domain entities.  Business logic normally involves multiple domain entities and collaborations between them.

In your architecture you should have a layer to compose business logic.  This usually corresponds to a service exposed to external.

This is usually the place you should have your transaction boundary set on.  Usually it is a Controller, or a Service method.

Comment: I agree with your answer about Transaction should be applied to Service method but not Controller's method or Repositories...

Comment: @Hamedz imho, as what I said in the answer, having transaction boundary around Controller could make sense, depending on your design/convention.  Though repository is rarely the correct place for transaction boundary.

Answer (score -3):

Steps to follow:

1. Ensure you use Interfaces for repo1 and repo2 methods as spring transactions works on proxy. ( If you use only classes, then you may need to add few other dependencies).
2. Annotate repo1.save(..) and repo2.save(..) with    @Transactional(propagation=[Propagation.REQUIRED](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED)) annotation.
3. Call repo1.save() from any method outside of class.
4. Unit test the code properly using [special junit runner](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html).